# Set reportviewer table header value dynamically

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer

I'm using reportviewer control in vb.net for creating local report.
I have a table in which the values of header are generated dynamically. I want to repeat the table header in every page. The problem is that, I can only insert static text into the header. Is there any way to set the header values using code?

Comment: Maybe use a parameter to send to ReportViewer and according to what it says in parameter it shows in report?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a data set (DataSet1) that points to your report data that has also a parameter (Parameter1) if necessary. This is for the case when your parameter affects the SQL statement that pulls report data as well (in this case the command string may be something like: SELECT * from myTable where myField <= :Parameter1).
2. Create a report that uses DataSet1 and has a parameter called ReportParameter1
3. Use the following code:

   Dim rds As New ReportDataSource
   Dim oTableAdapter As New DataSet1TableAdapters.yourTableAdapter
   Dim m_DataSet = New yourProjectName.DataSet1

   oTableAdapter.Connection.ConnectionString = your connection string

   oTableAdapter.Fill(m_DataSet.Tables(0), TextBox1.Text)

   rds.Name = m_DataSet.DataSetName
   rds.Value = m_DataSet.Tables(0)

   ReportViewer1.KeepSessionAlive = True
   With ReportViewer1.LocalReport
     .DataSources.Clear()
     .DataSources.Add(rds)
     .Refresh()
     .SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(New PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted))
   End With

   m_DataSet.Dispose()
   m_DataSet = Nothing
   oTableAdapter.Dispose()
   oTableAdapter = Nothing

   Dim myParam As New ReportParameter("ReportParameter1", TextBox1.Text)
   ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(myParam)

   rds = Nothing
   myParam = Nothing

[SOURCE](http://forums.asp.net/t/1844729.aspx)

Note: I don't know why but StackOverFlow won't give me a code reader.